# Change row number after occurrence of a specific value in one column using SQL

Tags: sql, hive

The requirement is to number the rows as per the state-PASS and order by the time for a specific id: so when every time PASS occurs in the state for one id it should icrement the number. and if pass does not occur it should maintain the number

I am currently trying to use

```
rank() over (partition by id, user, state = 'PASS' order by time)
```

but this works well till there is a pass alternately occuring but does not work if a pass does not occur

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

This is the sample data:

```
ID  user    State    time          Req. number
-----------------------------------------------
1    a1     work     timestamp1     1
1    f1     pass     timestamp2     1
1    s1     work     timestamp3     2
1    f1     pass     timestamp4     2
1    m1     break    timestamp5     3
1    s1     pass     timestamp6     3
1    f1     work     timestamp7     4
1    a1     pass     timestamp8     4
1    v1     work     timestamp9     5
1    s1     endwork  timestamp10    5
1    s1     endwork  timestamp11    5
1    a1     work     timestamp12    5
2    a2     work     timestamp13    1
2    s2     endwork  timestamp14    1
```

Comment: I doubt you are using MySQL here.  Please only tag with the database you are using, and remove the other incompatible tags.

Comment: Can you give 2 tables one what is the data you have in source and 2nd what you want to achieve ?

Comment: The source table is the first 4 columns . I only want to add the 4th Column (Req.Number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want one more than the cumulative number of "PASS"s up to the previous row:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(sum(case when state = 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end) over
                    (partition by id
                     order by time
                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                    ) + 1, 1
               )
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am sorry, just changed the Tag to 'Hive'. In hive the above query gives me an error saying : Invalid column reference 'time'. would you be able to suggest a solution for hive?

Comment: @MysticRenge . . . It is your data.  I don't know what the columns are called.  But the sample data in your question has a column called `time`.

Comment: its working. Thank you.I made was using select distinct t.* hence it was not working. @gordonLinoff just one more doubt: the code doesnt seem to work if there are consecutive 'PASS'.

Comment: @MysticRenge . . . That is a little hard to say.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, and include appropriate sample data and a good description of what should happen in this case.